# How can I authorize my laptop for USB Debugging if I can't see the screen?

Tags: data-recovery, usb-debugging, broken-screen, remote-control, accessibility

I use USB Debugging to control this phone because the screen is missing. Not broken, missing. The LCD and display assembly is literally gone. I simply can't see what's on the screen without USB Debugging.

I used to be able to use Vysor to control the phone. That worked for years I think. But recently it started refusing to let me do that. Vysor says that it needs me to authorize the computer by tapping OK in a dialog.

This is BAD! I can't do ANYTHING with the phone without Vysor working! I can't tap anything or even see what's on the screen. The only thing I can do is press the volume buttons and power button.

I tried looking up guides, but they're all:

- "use dr.fone": all are blatant advertisements so no
- connect a mouse: missing screen so can't see
- use clockworkmod/twrp: bootloader isn't unlocked
- connect a hdmi: all my phone has is a USB-C port, and those adapters are expensive... I would need one that has both a HDMI port and a USB port so I can use a mouse to work it, oh and I would also probably need to connect it to my computer at the same time to make the authorization dialog pop up so it's complicated and impossible for me

I think the phone's running Android 6, and there is no password or anything (lock screen is a simple slide/tap to unlock I think). But I have no idea what to do.

How do I authorize my computer again so I can control the phone?

(Also, I'm sorry if the tone of this post is a bit off. I was very annoyed when writing it. Eventually I got what I needed without having to access the broken phone, but I'm leaving this question up because it's nice to have and could bear some future value for googlers.)

Comment: If Vysor really only want's you to press OK then you may succeed by attaching a simple keyboard via USB OTG and then accept this dialog via Return key. This is the only chance I see at the moment.